# How to define a custom shape in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes

I have created a shape and selected a layer.
In the Edit menu the `Define custom shape...` option is disabled.

Can any one tell what mistake I have made.

[image]

Comment: Need more info. How did you "create a shape"? What tools did you use? Did you try selecting the path with the Selection tool first?

Comment: i had used pentool to draw a shape...ya i tried pathselection also,,but define custom shape is in disable state only

Comment: Is the path highlighted in the Path Panel? The path must be highlighted there to define a custom shape.

Comment: yes path is highlighted only,,,,but i dont know where i am doing mistake.

Comment: It looks like you did it correct. Check on the layers palette and click on the right side square thing, it should change to have white around it although it looks like it does in your screenshot. Otherwise going off your screenshot everything looks correct so if thats not it the problem isn't in your screenshot so will be very hard for us to answer.

Comment: The bit you're missing is in plainclothes' answer: you have to explicitly select the path, not just target the layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the path on the canvas with the Direct Selection Tool (white arrow). Define Custom Shape should activate for you then.

[image]

Comment: i tried this but not getting

Comment: Try performing the same steps in a fresh file. If that still doesn't work, I'm afraid something is broken with your copy of Pshop then. Time to start the hunt for corruption.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a "Shape layer" or "Work path" to be able to define a custom shape.

1) As first click on rectangle tool and then on shape layers selector

[image]
[image]

2) After that draw a new layer and click with a right mouse button on that layer. You will see "Define Custom shape" option

[image]

3) Or you can create a new layer with a pen tool

[image]

4) And then take a "Path selection tool" and right-click this layer

[image]

Comment: i tried like this but Define Custom Shape is in disable stare only....i dont know were i am making mistake

Answer (score 1):

I was running into the same issue. I solved it by allowing all shapes to be loaded within the shapes. Right after that I was able to define my shape.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have too many shapes delete some it will get activated.

Did this happen to me recently, it took me a long time to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

Custom shapes can only be made from paths. If you're working with a selection and not a path, you need to first convert the selection into a path. To do this, open the Paths panel and click on the icon that looks like a circle crosshair (Cross with a circle overlaid) which is the "Make work path from selection" button. This will convert your selection into a path. Once you've done this, you will see the Define custom shape option is working.